# SASS scoping with @include and ampersand (&)

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to scope an existing SASS library such that all rules begin with `.my-scope`. My first iteration was:

```
.my-scope {
  @import library;
}
```

This works for most things, but the library has a mixin as follows:

```
@mixin foo {
  input:checked ~ & {
    background: red;
  }
}

@mixin library {
  .bar {
    @include foo;
  }
}
```

This results in

```
input:checked ~ .my-scope .bar{background:red}
```

My intention is to generate

```
.my-scope input:checked ~ .bar{background:red}
```

instead.

I can't change the library; is there a way I can structure my `@import` to get the scoping to work?

Comment: No, there is not. You could achieve so, but changing all the mixins, otherwise, that will be imposible to achieve.

Comment: @muecas can you elaborate on why you believe it is impossible?

Comment: Basically because of the usage of `&`. You could scope a basic template if the template does not use `&` on any selector to match the parent selector. But as long as the library uses `&` to create class names (like BEM or just nested classes) it will be imposible to achieve, by the simple fact that `&` will be a reference to the full parent class (including the class name you added for scoping). So as long as you can't modify the mixins or the `&` usage, you won't be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Follow this issue here https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2191